# Symfony equivalent of curl_setopt using the httpClientInterface service

Tags: php, api, symfony, curl, symfony-http-client

I need to make a call to an external API.
The API docs says

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.simkl.com/search/file");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
  \"file\": \"Were.The.Fugawis.S01E01E02.WS.DSR.x264-NY2.mkv\",
  \"part\": 1
}");
```

I'm using Symfony and trying to use correctly the given service `HttpClientInterface` to make the call with:

```
// $this->client containing the Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface service 
$response = $this->client->request('POST', 'https://api.simkl.com/search/file', [
    'file' => 'Death_Note-01',
]);
```

Of course it returns the error

> Unsupported option "file" passed to Symfony\Component\HttpClient\NativeHttpClient", did you mean cafile"?

How to properly set the call options using the HttpClientInterface provided by Symfony?

Can't find an answer anywhere in the Symfony docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#configuring-curlhttpclient-options):

```
$response = $this->client->request('POST', 'https://api.simkl.com/search/file', [
    'extra' => [
        'curl' => [
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{
               \"file\": \"Were.The.Fugawis.S01E01E02.WS.DSR.x264-NY2.mkv\",
               \"part\": 1
             }",
        ],
    ],
]);
```